# How do I use variables of some class in a different class ( ConsumerDescAndEdit.java ) through onItemClickListener?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I need to display `name`, `phoneNumber` and `accountNumber` in `EditText` in the class `ConsumerdescAndEdit`, so how do pass these values when `OnItemClickListener` is executed?

**ShowAll.java**:

I have the `ListView` that inflated from `CustomAdapter`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ShowAll.this,ConsumerDescAndEdit.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**CustomAdapter.java:**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;

    TextView nameView;
    TextView phoneNumberView;
    TextView accountView;

    String name;
    String phoneNumber;
    String accountNumber;

    ArrayList<Consumer> objects;


    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Consumer> objects){

        this.objects = objects;
        this.mContext = context;

    }
    public CustomAdapter(){

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Consumer consumer = (Consumer) getItem(position);

        // Values to be displayed.

        name = consumer.getName();
        phoneNumber = consumer.getPhoneNumber();
        accountNumber = consumer.getAccountNumber();


        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext); // generate an inflater using context.
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_layout,null); // inflate details_layout and store it in convertView.

        nameView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameView);
        phoneNumberView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumberView);
        accountView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.accountView);

        nameView.setText(name);
        phoneNumberView.setText(phoneNumber);
        accountView.setText(accountNumber);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**ConsumerDescAndEdit.java** (where do I need to use variables):

```
public class ConsumerDescAndEdit extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button updateButton;

    EditText nameEditTextVar;
    EditText phoneEditTextVar;
    EditText accountEditTextVar;

    //      Variables to store user inputted data.
    String nameEdit;
    String phoneEdit;
    String accountEdit;

    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_consumer_desc_and_edit);

        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        updateButton = findViewById(R.id.updateButton);

        nameEditTextVar = findViewById(R.id.nameEditScreen);
        phoneEditTextVar = findViewById(R.id.phoneNumberEditScreen);
        accountEditTextVar = findViewById(R.id.accountNumberEditScreen);

        String s_intent = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID");
        nameEditTextVar.setText(s_intent);


        updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                nameEdit = nameEditTextVar.getText().toString();
                phoneEdit = phoneEditTextVar.getText().toString();
                accountEdit = accountEditTextVar.getText().toString();

                if (nameEdit.isEmpty() || phoneEdit.isEmpty() || accountEdit.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(ConsumerDescAndEdit.this, "Data Insufficient", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    boolean b = dbHelper.updateData(nameEdit, phoneEdit, accountEdit);
                    if (b)
                        Toast.makeText(ConsumerDescAndEdit.this, "Data updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(ConsumerDescAndEdit.this, "Could not update data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the `Intent` for the edit `Activity`, add the data from the selected item as "extras" to the `Intent`, like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ShowAll.this,ConsumerDescAndEdit.class);
intent.putExtra("name", name);
intent.putExtra("phone", phone);
intent.putExtra("account", account);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the edit `Activity`, extract the data from the `Intent` like this:

```
String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
String phone = intent.getStringExtra("phone");
String account = intent.getStringExtra("account");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;

    TextView nameView;
    TextView phoneNumberView;
    TextView accountView;

    String name;
    String phoneNumber;
    String accountNumber;

    ArrayList<Consumer> objects;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(Consumer consumer);
    }


    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Consumer> objects, ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.objects = objects;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public CustomAdapter() {

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Consumer consumer = (Consumer) getItem(position);

        // Values to be displayed.

        name = consumer.getName();
        phoneNumber = consumer.getPhoneNumber();
        accountNumber = consumer.getAccountNumber();


        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext); // generate an inflater using context.
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_layout, null); // inflate details_layout and store it in convertView.

        nameView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameView);
        phoneNumberView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumberView);
        accountView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.accountView);

        nameView.setText(name);
        phoneNumberView.setText(phoneNumber);
        accountView.setText(accountNumber);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (itemClickListener != null) {
                    itemClickListener.onItemClick(consumer);
                }

            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

In Activity do following

```
public class ConsumerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CustomAdapter.ItemClickListener {
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Consumer> objects;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_consumer);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, objects, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(Consumer consumer) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CustomerEdit.class);
        intent.putExtra("Consumer", consumer);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```